# Devise, cancan, and namespace routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I have a namespace in my router like so:

```
namespace :my do
    resources :addressbookitems
end
```

and in `controllers/my/addressbookitems_controller.rb` I have, for example, actions `index` and `show`.

I would like to limit resources accessible to my users differently based on the namespace: if they access `/addressbookitems` I would like to have different abilities then with `/my/addressbookitems`. How would i structure my Ability class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authorizing Namespaced and Nested controllers using CanCan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334367/authorizing-namespaced-and-nested-controllers-using-cancan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With plain cancan I think the only option would be to override all behavior:

```
can do |action, subject_class, subject|
  # custom logic to allow or deny permission
end
```

They show an example of this here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Abilities-in-Database

The other option would be use the `cancan_namespace` gem: https://github.com/galetahub/cancan_namespace

Comment: In cancan 1.6.10, this is no longer necessary.  Ability definitions can [specify namespace](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/pull/675)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then you want to give edit, delete etc abilities when user owns this model. If so then you could do it like:

```
can update, AddressBookItem, :user_id => user.id
can destroy, AddressBookItem, :user_id => user.id
```

If you have more complicated logic behind it then:

```
can update, AddressBookItem do |item|
  item.user == user and item.state == :something
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not quite what I am looking for. Rather I am looking for different ability logic for controllers e.g. ReportController and My::ReportController, although they share the model.