# Authorizing Namespaced and Nested controllers using CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I having quite a bit of troubling getting cancan to authorize my new routes setup below:

```
namespace :api do
namespace :v1 do
  resources :users do
    resources :user_songs
    resources :friendships
    resources :plays
    resources :likes
    resources :songs
```

I have followed what was posted here https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources and tested it with the likes controller by putting this above:

```
class Api::V1::LikesController < Api::V1::BaseController

load_and_authorize_resource :user
load_and_authorize_resource :like, :through => :user
```

Using a can :access, :all in ability.rb works but anything else I have tried to limit is has not for example:

```
can :access, :likes
can :access, Like
can :access, :users
can :access, User
can :access, [:"users/likes", :users_likes]
```

I am not too sure if the blame is because of the namespace routes or not. Any guidance would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out the answer: It was the namespace after all, it just needed a

`can :access, "api/v1/likes"`

Comment: Seems like this only works for get requests and not post requests added can :create, "api/v1/likes" to see if it mattered and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Figured it out needed a can :access, :likes right below it for it to work.

Comment: There was a bug with this, but it's been [fixed in 1.6.10](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/pull/675)